# How to smoothly operate when time interval is short and Timer1_Tick update database and bind data again?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When timer interval is short and timer tick run database operation and update **asp.net** web user interface,
I can not type text or select **DropDownList**.

How to make not influence use's operation when it real time operate database?

If there are many users, I afraid influence the performance of database such as slow

i have set it update when change, but still quite often to intervene operation, such as i can not select dropdownlist or can not type in textbox

```
</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" /> 
    </Triggers> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] last_serial_no = new string[Calculator_GridView.Rows.Count];
            string[] last_a1_textbox = new string[Calculator_GridView.Rows.Count];
            string[] last_b1_textbox = new string[Calculator_GridView.Rows.Count];
            string[] last_mp_dropdown = new string[Calculator_GridView.Rows.Count];

            bool change = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < Calculator_GridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string serial_no = Calculator_GridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                string a1_textbox = Calculator_GridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
                string b1_textbox = Calculator_GridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
                DropDownList mp_dropdown = (DropDownList)Calculator_GridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[1];

                //TextBox Result_textbox = (TextBox)Calculator_GridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[0];

                if (last_serial_no[i] != serial_no ||
                last_a1_textbox[i] != a1_textbox ||
                last_b1_textbox[i] != b1_textbox ||
                last_mp_dropdown[i] != mp_dropdown.SelectedValue)
                {
                    string executestring = "";
                    executestring = "Update cal set a1=" + a1_textbox;
                    executestring = executestring + ", b1=" + b1_textbox;
                    executestring = executestring + ", mp=" + mp_dropdown.SelectedValue;
                    executestring = executestring + ", result=" + (Convert.ToDouble(mp_dropdown.SelectedValue) * Convert.ToDouble(b1_textbox)).ToString();
                    executestring = executestring + " where [識別碼]=" + serial_no;
                    ExecuteDatabase(executestring);

                    change = true;
                }
                last_serial_no[i] = serial_no;
                last_a1_textbox[i] = a1_textbox;
                last_b1_textbox[i] = b1_textbox;
                last_mp_dropdown[i] = mp_dropdown.SelectedValue;
            }

            if (change == true)
            {
                string connstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/db1.mdb";
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr);
                conn.ConnectionString = connstr;

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

                OleDbCommand get_info_cmd = null;
                get_info_cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [識別碼], [a1], [b1], [result], [mp] FROM [cal]", conn);

                OleDbDataReader get_info_Reader = get_info_cmd.ExecuteReader();

                store.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("識別碼", typeof(int)));
                store.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("a1", typeof(double)));
                store.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("b1", typeof(double)));
                store.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mp", typeof(double)));
                store.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("result", typeof(double)));

                DataRow dr;

                try
                {
                    while (get_info_Reader.Read())
                    {
                        dr = store.NewRow();
                        dr[0] = get_info_Reader["識別碼"].ToString();
                        dr[1] = get_info_Reader["a1"].ToString();
                        dr[2] = get_info_Reader["b1"].ToString();
                        dr[3] = get_info_Reader["mp"].ToString();
                        dr[4] = (Convert.ToDouble(get_info_Reader["b1"].ToString()) * Convert.ToDouble(get_info_Reader["mp"].ToString())).ToString();

                        store.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Error_Label.Text = Error_Label.Text + ex.ToString();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    get_info_cmd.Dispose();
                    get_info_Reader.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                storeview = new DataView(store);

                Calculator_GridView.Font.Size = new FontUnit(10);
                Calculator_GridView.DataSourceID = "";
                Calculator_GridView.DataSource = storeview;
                Calculator_GridView.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us some code.

Comment: edited, not only update database but also only validate textbox in real time, it also influence operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon that you should be doing the DB operation in a seperate thread. Also, how are you updating the ASP.Net page as mentioned?

Comment: if i do not update database and just validate textbox in real time, it also influence the operation such as typing in text box